# POSIX and ACL permissions Mac Server

Tags: mac, terminal, permissions, acl, posix

I have a mac mini server and have a script run at login for network users that mounts a shared drive on the mac server.

When they mount up, I create a folder with their name as the folder name. What I'm attempting to do is create the permission so that our admin has full control over the folders inside, but each user is only able to access their own folder.

Users are currently in a group called OSX Users.

The folder structure is as follows

| FolderShare

|
|--User 1

|
|--User 2

and so on..

I've used chmod ACL commands but to no avail, the operation is supported (on the user side). Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: idk how to do it from chmod, but from the get info GUI, set the share to admin read & write, group read only, everyone read only. Then user 1's folder to admin read/write, user 1 read/write, everyone no access.

Comment: Well, you could create a group that only your admins belong to and set the ownership of `user1:admins` with permissions to `rwxrwx---` and a `umask 007`, but that feels pretty lame.  I suppose sticky bitting the group would give you some semblance of protection, though.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions guys, I ended up enabling ACLs on the Mac Server and configuring them, allowing the user to create a folder on login and then the folder would chmod 700 so only the user could access that folder, but the ACL for the admin would give full control. Thanks for the suggestions though, they were a good start